# Collection Reference is invalid in Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

The NextJS app was working fine a few days ago and now giving the following error. Nothing has changed in backend and table still exists.

> Unhandled Runtime Error
> FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

My firebase config file

```
import { initializeApp, getApp, getApps } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: XXX,
  authDomain: XXX,
  projectId: XXX,
  storageBucket: XXX,
  messagingSenderId: XXX,
  appId: XXX,
  measurementId: XXX,
};

const app = !getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);
    
export { app, auth, db, storage };
```

And the **useEffect** inside the function component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import {
  onSnapshot,
  collection,
  addDoc,
  getDocs,
  orderBy,
  query,
  where,
  limit,
  QuerySnapshot,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../../config/firebase";

    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const q = query(
          collection(db, "user_info"),
          orderBy("name", "asc")
        );
    
    
        
        getDocs(q).then((querySnapshot) => {
          const docs = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            docs.push(doc.data());
          });
          setUsers(docs);
        });
      }, []);
```

Also, tried using #useCollectionData from 'react-firebase-hooks', however, the same error happens.

```
  #This works
  console.log(db)


  const myCollectionRef = collection(db, 'users');
  const myCollectionQuery = query(myCollectionRef);
  const [users, reactloading, reacterror] = useCollectionData(myCollectionQuery);

  #This does not
  console.log('users',users)
```

**Seems like the app works fine as in getting data in the pages at root level, however, the firestore collection and query function breaks if used in the nested route.**

Comment: Is it possible the error is coming from another component? In this example, can you put a `.catch((e) => console.log(e))` at the end of your `getDocs` call so we can verify the error message is the same here? --- Also can you please output your `"../../config/firebase"` file. One other thing would be to test locally using the `connectEmulator` function and the local `firebase emulators:start` function. Currently, what you have looks fine and we need more info.

Comment: Thanks @WesleyLeMahieu . The firebase config file is the same file with export of db, auth, and other

Comment: Where is your Firebase config file in relation to your project root file? Is it `Vite` or `CRA`? What file is calling your config file? Also, where is your functional component in the file structure? Not quite enough information but I have a theory.

Comment: Thanks @WesleyLeMahieu. Tried adding the console.log to see if the "db" exists and it does. The problem seems to be coming from "collection" keyword.